# Path "/src/app/app.module.ts" does not exist while doing ng add in Angular project with custom path

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-universal

I was trying to add angular universal to my project. My folder structure is as below.

- src

  - main

    - app

      - app.module.ts
  - node_modules
  - tsconfig.json

I am using angular 15.2.5.
Angular universal latest version
The package is getting installed but its throwing this error 'Path "/src/app/app.module.ts" does not exist'
And server files are also not created for the angular universal. Its just my project path has app folder inside main but ng add is trying to take the path src/app.
Could any one help with how to customize that?

Please let me know if any further info is needed

I tried adding the path attribute as "paths": { "@app/*": ["src/main/app/*"] }

I tried doing ng add inside src and inside main.

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix the problem, but you aren't supposed to add `.ts` in your import path

Comment: Also, the file structure seems off. The `src` folder is usually at the same level as `node_modules` and `tsconfig.json`, but here they are at the same level as the `main` folder. That is most likely the error; change `{ "@app/": ["src/main/app/"] }` to `{ "@app/": ["main/app/"] }`

Comment: Hi, thanks Parzh. For the first comment, i didn't import anything manually. I just used the cli to generate all the files. just 'ng add @angular @nguniversal/express-engine'. For the second, yes that folder structure was made so according to the requirement. And when i changed src/main/app to just main/app it didnt work. i am now manually adding all the sever files required for angular universal. please let me know if there is any other workaround.